# Error in header files - Visual Studio C++

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i am using visual studio C++ since some days. While programming a C project, I have included the header for example winnt.h. 
But the compiler says that there are a lot of syntax errors in winnt.h . What should I do ? 
I have read the following topic at [Errors within standard header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333372/errors-within-standard-header-files)
which seems that is the same but i did not understand what I should do.

Can somebody help me?

Some of the over hundred errors are the following:

```
  c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\tlhelp32.h(155):error C2059: syntax error : ';'

  c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\tlhelp32.h(156):error C2143: syntax error : 'WINAPI' missing
```

There are a lot of errors of that type. They are all in the headers that I have used.

Comment: Without knowing what type of project and what the specific errors are, I don't think we can help you.

Comment: at the moment, i have only one file in my project. I called it main.c and in that file, i want to call the function "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot". For that function, I must include the header "tlHelp32.h". But when I do that, the compiler shows me syntax errrors located in "tlHelp32.h" although it is not from me.

Comment: "syntax errors" ... please make sure you post the exact errors (like I said before). If you can't be specific, we can't help.

Comment: there are exactly the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333372/errors-within-standard-header-files . Except that I have other header files used

Comment: So... exactly the same messages for completely different header files? I'm guessing not.

Comment: I have edited my question. See above for the syntax errors.

Comment: Did you try adding `#include <windows.h>` as your first include? The other windows headers might rely on things defined in it.

Comment: No, I didn't. But now I included windows.h and the errors doesnt appear anymore. Thx, for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same kind of error. But the error disappeared after i interchange 
stdafx.h with windows.h which means .. I put #include "stdafx.h" first and #include "windows.h" on second.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I don't know why there is a more line

`namcespace A` (in .h file)

Before `#include <tlhelp32.h>` (in .cpp file)

So, it can't compile. Deleting the needless one solves the problem.